# How to make this function more efficient? Using a very large file

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I'm using a very large csv file (around 716k rows) in these functions. They work fast with a small file but with such a big amount of rows I've left it for an hour and it didn't even end. 
The thing is at certain point I call the function 'LIMPIA_REPETIDOS()'

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LIMPIA_REPETIDOS() 
    RETURNS VOID AS $$

    DECLARE 
        REP RECORD;
        cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT usuario, fecha_hora_ret FROM auxi;            

    begin
        open cursor1;
        LOOP
            FETCH cursor1 INTO REP;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            PERFORM GUARDA(REP.usuario, REP.fecha_hora_ret);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cursor1;
    end;

    $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;



    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GUARDA
    (myid auxi.usuario%TYPE, my_time auxi.fecha_hora_ret%type) RETURNS VOID AS $$


    DECLARE
        mycursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM auxi
        WHERE myid = usuario AND my_time = fecha_hora_ret
        ORDER BY tiempo_uso ASC;
        CANT INT;
        devolucion TIMESTAMP;
        mystruct RECORD;
        mystruct2 RECORD;


    BEGIN

     OPEN mycursor;
     CANT = 0;
            FETCH mycursor INTO mystruct;
                    FETCH mycursor INTO mystruct2;

                            IF mystruct2.usuario = mystruct.usuario AND mystruct2.fecha_hora_ret = mystruct.fecha_hora_ret THEN
                                     devolucion = crear_fecha_hora_devolucion(mystruct2.tiempo_uso, mystruct2.fecha_hora_ret);
                                     INSERT INTO RECORRIDO_FINAL VALUES(mystruct2.periodo, mystruct2.usuario, mystruct2.fecha_hora_ret, mystruct2.est_origen, mystruct2.est_origen, devolucion);

                            ELSE
                                    devolucion = crear_fecha_hora_devolucion(mystruct.tiempo_uso, mystruct.fecha_hora_ret);
                                    INSERT INTO RECORRIDO_FINAL VALUES(mystruct.periodo, mystruct.usuario, mystruct.fecha_hora_ret, mystruct.est_origen, mystruct.est_origen, devolucion);

                            END IF;


     CLOSE mycursor;   

   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

What I'm doing here is to select rows from a table called 'auxi' which has all the rows from that file (except some with null values but this works fast enough) and then transfer them to another one. The thing is when I have two or more rows in 'auxi' with the same values for 'usuario' and 'fecha_hora_ret' I have to sort those by 'tiempo_uso' and then select the second one. I don't know why it takes so much time.
How can I make it faster?

Table auxi has PRIMARY KEY(periodo, usuario,fecha_hora_ret,est_origen, est_destino, tiempo_uso)
[image]
And table recorrido_final PRIMARY KEY(usuario,fecha_hora_ret)
[image]

I'm desperate and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you show a code of `devolucion = crear_fecha_hora_devolucion(mystruct.tiempo_uso, mystruct.fecha_hora_ret);` function, or explain what this function is supossed to do ?

Comment: Use plprofiler and auto_explain to see where exactly the time is spent. Then tune that part.

Answer (score 0):

The LOOP in code and the additional function call may be responsible for degraded performance.  Can you not simply select the maximum value of `tiempo_uso` for each combination of other PK columns with a query like this:

```
select
    periodo,
    usuario,
    fecha_hora_ret,
    est_origen,
    est_destino,
    max(tiempo_uso) as max_tiempo_uso
from
    auxi
group by
    periodo,
    usuario,
    fecha_hora_ret,
    est_origen,
    est_destino;
```

And use that as a data source for the INSERT INTO statement?  This avoids function calls and looping in code.

Comment: The thing is I need the second row when I sort by 'tiempo_uso'. If I have more rows I always need to choose the second one.

Comment: That's what the `max()` aggregate function and the GROUP BY clause will give you.

Answer (score 0):

Processing data using cursors is usually quite inefficient and not needed, because it be replaced by set-prcessing in most cases.

If you need to find the most recent row you can probably use a simple ROW_NUMBER:

```
select periodo, usuario, fecha_hora_ret, est_origen, est_origen
  ,crear_fecha_hora_devolucion(tiempo_uso, fecha_hora_ret) as devolucion
FROM
 (
    select periodo, usuario, fecha_hora_ret, est_origen, est_origen
      ,crear_fecha_hora_devolucion(tiempo_uso, fecha_hora_ret) as devolucion
      ,row_number() -- most recent row per usuario/fecha_hora_ret
       over (partition by usuario, fecha_hora_ret
             ORDER BY tiempo_uso DESC) as rn
    from auxi
 ) as dt
where rn = 1
```